# how to put Boolean in clause where in Doctrine query?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

here is my query :

```
$passAdmin = true;
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('e,l')
                ->from('Application\Entity\Table','e')  
                ->innerJoin('e.fkUser', 'l')
                ->where(" l.email like '$name' ")
                ->andWhere(" l.mdp = '".Sha1($password)."' OR $passAdmin ");
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$resultEditeurs = $query->getResult();
```

it gives me an error in doctrine , but it works in mysql.

**Error :**

```
Message:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 172: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got ')' Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php(396):
```

Comment: what error? what do you want to acheive precisely?

Comment: i want to check if the password is correct or if is allowed by the variable $passAdmin.

Comment: the error in the edited post

Comment: you sure that $passAdmin is boolean?, check $qb->getQuery()->getSql()

Comment: $passAdmin is a simple php variable that i created, it's not stored in bdd

Comment: try with passAdmin = 1 or 'true'